# How to throw an error message on the console, if a float is entered instead of an int in C

Tags: c, types, scanf

So I was asked to write a function `int ncr(int n, int r)`, which basically computes n choose r and returns the value, but, my code also needs to account for error cases if the user enters negative numbers or invalid input like n lesser than r (or) if the user enters floating point numbers

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int ncr(int n, int r)
{
    if (n - r < r)
    {
        r = n - r;
    }
    
    if (r == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else return ncr(n-1,r) + ncr(n-1,r-1);
}

int main()
{
    int n, r;
    float n1, r1;
    printf("Input :\n");
    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%f", &n1);
    printf("r = ");
    scanf("%f", &r1);
    printf("Output : ");
    
    n = n1;
    r = r1;

    if (n1 - n > 0 || r1 - r > 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid Input, n and r both should be integer numbers");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (n <= 0 || r < 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid input, n (or) r should be unsigned numbers");
    }
    else if (n < r)
    {
        printf("Invalid input, n should be greater than or equal to r");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("C(n, r) = %d", ncr(n,r));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This piece of code works completely fine but, the thing I am concerned with is that there must surely be a better way to account for throwing an error message if the user enters floating point numbers. I handled this case by actually reading a `float` using `scanf("%f", &n1)` and `scanf("%f", &r1)` and later checking whether these floats are just integers or not and accordingly thrown the error if these numbers also have digits after the decimal point.

Instead of using these `float` duplicates like `n1` and `r1`, can we just not solve the issue by using only `int n, r` directly?

I've tried doing this too where I read the input directly into `n` and `r` without using any float duplicates like `n1` and `r1`

```c
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
    {
        printf("Output : Invalid Input, n and r both should be integer numbers");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("r = ");
    if (scanf("%d", &r) != 1)
    {
        printf("Output : Invalid Input, n and r both should be integer numbers");
        return 1;
    }
```

But the output is not satisfying

```
Input :
n = 6.7
r = Output : Invalid Input, n and r both should be integer numbers
```

It appears that contro-flow is not going into the first `if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1)` statement but is going into the second one (I can tell this because `r =`  is being printed on-screen)

This all seems insignificant but it would be great if someone tells a better way to throw an error message if the user enters a `float` instead of an `int` without actually reading `float` numbers like I did (i.e., using duplicates)

Comment: You don't want to do anything with a "console" or a tty (probably less than 1% of terminals are consoles, and it wouldn't surprise me if that number is closer to .0001%).  Write your error messages to stderr and let the caller determine to what device that message is written.

Comment: Don't use `scanf`.  Use `fgets` to read the line and then use `strtol` to parse it.

Comment: Is this an exercise you're getting graded on, or a personal challenge to yourself, or a practical (production) program, or what?  Reading and validating user input using `scanf` is notoriously difficult, and it's not trivial even if you [don't use `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537), but it may not matter so much, because few "real" programs use text input like this any more anyway.  If you want to, say, learn how to write a good `ncr` function, I'd concentrate on that, and work just hard enough on my input code that I can get valid integers in to test with.

Comment: Seriously, the fact that you've declared `ncr` as `int ncr(int n, int r)` provides a pretty good guarantee that its inputs are not going to be floating point!

Comment: @Steve-summit Yeah, this is an assignment on which I will be graded on. Yes, this input formatting using `scanf()` is being difficult to account for all possible cases. Yeah cool, that's what I am thinking about that all this juglary with input formatting is going too far.

Comment: @Steve-summit, And btw are you that Steve Summit who maintains that faqs in c-language? I am going through that now. Thank you.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks, I will look into that

Comment: @SteveSummit Seemed I didn't tag you properly, yes, the function declaration does take only integer inputs, but, the professor wants to see an error message. Anyway, this does not seem too important of a thing to concentrate much on